# Python ldap returns empty list

Tags: python, ldap

I tested my ldap query with `ldapsearch` before I rewrote it to python's ldap module. The very same query works fine with `ldapsearch` but returns an empty array in python.

```
ldapsearch -H [hostname] -LLL -b [base] -D [user] -w [password] -x "city=Bratislava"
```

In python:

```
ldap_obj = ldap.initialize(ldap_config.LDAP_SERVER)
ldap_obj.simple_bind(ldap_config.LDAP_USER, ldap_config.LDAP_PASSWORD)
ldap_results_obj = ldap_obj.search(
    ldap_config.LDAP_BASE_DN,
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    'city=Bratislava',
)
results = ldap_obj.result(ldap_results_obj)
print results
```

I tried using a different filter, i.e. `uid=bmakan` and this one worked both in `ldapsearch` and python's ldap. It only returned an empty list when I used a filter that returns multiple ldap entires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are asynchronous and synchronous methods available. You probably want to use the synchronous methods ending with `_s`.

See also: [python-ldap -- Sending LDAP requests](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#sending-ldap-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but using `LDAPObject.simple_bind_s` instead of `LDAPObject.simple_bind` fixed the issue I faced. The documentation is quite vague on the difference on these two functions except that the latter returns an integer ([docs](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.simple_bind)).

This change also fixed another issue I faced - with `LDAPObject.simple_bind`, `LDAPObject.search`'s `attrlist` parameter wasn't working correctly - it only returned the first attribute.

If anyone can provide more info, I'd be happy to hear it out.